# es posible validar campos de formRequest desde otro metodo?

Tags: laravel, formrequest

Como puedo validar campos con formRequest, estoy llamando un metodo de otra clase.

este es el metodo que quiero llamar:

```
class somethingController extends Controller
{
   public function store(CreateRequest $request){
      return true;
   }
}
```

Lo estoy llamando de esta manera:

```
class somethingDosController extends Controller
{
   public function something(){
     $class = new \App\Http\Controllers\somethingController();
     $request = \App\Http\Requests\CreateRequest::capture();
     $request->merge(['number' => "ocho"]); 
     $callMethod = $class->store($request);
  }
}
```

Mi formRequest **CreateRequest** es:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'number' => 'required|Integer'
    ];
}
```

No logro que me lo valide el campo **number** cuando llamo el metodo store, yo envio un string y me lo deja pasar, ayuda!!!!

Comment: Aunque fuese posible... ¿Qué sentido tendría hacer algo así? Lo que planteas parece un problema XY

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Sí es posible hacerlo, debes utilizar la clase `Validator` (use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;)

```
Validator::validate([
    'number' => 'required|Integer',
]);
```

Pero no te recomiendo hacerlo de esa forma porque si luego tu proyecto se expande y tu código crece vas a tener un código "Spaghetti" donde vas a validar desde múltiples lugares y va a ser muy difícil de resolver problemas.

Lo mejor sería que tu controlador `somethingController` tuviera un método de validación y desde el método `store()` lo validaras

Algo más o menos así

```
class somethingController extends Controller
{
    public function validar(CreateRequest $request){
        Validator::validate([
            'number' => 'required|Integer',
        ]);
    }

    public function store(CreateRequest $request){
        $this->validar($request)
        return true;
    }
}
```